# Asynchronous code problem in flutter, need my code to run line by line

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous

I'm trying to build a flutter app for the first time and I'm having a lot of trouble to get it done. I'm having problem especially with asynchronous coding. I have a persistent bottom nav bar for the home of a page. What I want from the Form nab button is to check if the logged in user already fill up a form or not. If the user didnt fill out the form, then I want to show DonorFormHomeBefore() and if the user already filled out the form then whenever pressed to the Form from nav bar, I want to show DonorFormHomeAfter(). To implement this, I used a wrapper and tried to get database instance from firebase. But, instead of fetching the data from firebase, the code runs the later part of the codes and causing error.

```
class DonorHome extends StatelessWidget {

  final DonorAuthService _auth = DonorAuthService();

  final PersistentTabController _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
        return [
        DonorRequests(),
        DonorProfile(),
        DonorFormWrapper(),
        ];
  }
.....
```

```
class DonorAuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //get database instance
  Future getDatabaseInstance(String uid) async{
    /*await Firestore.instance.collection("Donor Lists").document(uid).get().then((value) {
      print(value.data);
      return value.data;
    });*/

    final value = await Firestore.instance.collection('Donor Lists').document(uid).get();
    print(value.data);
    return value.data;

  }
```

```
class DonorFormWrapper extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _DonorFormWrapperState createState() => _DonorFormWrapperState();
}

class _DonorFormWrapperState extends State<DonorFormWrapper>{
  bool before;

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {

    final DonorAuthService _auth = DonorAuthService();


    final user = Provider.of<DonorUser>(context);

    print(user.uid);
    dynamic x = _auth.getDatabaseInstance(user.uid);

    print(x);
      if (x['name'] == 'name') {
        before = true;
        print(before);
        return DonorFormHomeBefore();
      }
      else {
        before = false;
        print(before);
        return DonorFormHomeAfter();
      }
    //print('before');
    //print(before);

    /*if (before == true || before == null) {
      return DonorFormHomeBefore();
    } 
    else if(before == false) {
      return DonorFormHomeAfter();
    } */
    /*return Container(
      height: 0.0, width: 0.0,
    );*/
  }
}
```

Here before it's fetching data and return that into "x", its running to to later portion of the code and getting a error of this:

```
Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building DonorFormWrapper(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<DonorUser>], state: _DonorFormWrapperState#a1b86):
Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
Tried calling: []("name")

The relevant error-causing widget was
    DonorFormWrapper 
lib\…\Home\donor_home.dart:21
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _DonorFormWrapperState.build 
package:PlasmaBank/…/Home/donor_form_wrapper.dart:33
#2      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4619
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4502
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4675
...
```

After using this code

```
class DonorFormWrapper extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _DonorFormWrapperState createState() => _DonorFormWrapperState();
}

class _DonorFormWrapperState extends State<DonorFormWrapper>{
  Future<dynamic> _initUserFuture;
  bool before;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final DonorAuthService _auth = DonorAuthService();
    final user = Provider.of<DonorUser>(context);

    print(user.uid);
    _initUserFuture = _auth.getDatabaseInstance(user.uid);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initUserFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.data['name'] == 'name') {
            before = true;
            print(before);
            return DonorFormHomeBefore();
          } else {
            before = false;
            print(before);
            return DonorFormHomeAfter();
          }
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error I got

```
Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building DefaultTextStyle(debugLabel: (englishLike body1 2014).merge(blackMountainView bodyText2), inherit: false, color: Color(0xdd000000), family: Roboto, size: 14.0, weight: 400, baseline: alphabetic, decoration: TextDecoration.none, softWrap: wrapping at box width, overflow: clip):
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<DonorUser>>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _DonorFormWrapperState.initState() completed.

When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.

Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.

The relevant error-causing widget was
    PersistentTabView 
lib\…\Home\donor_home.dart:68
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      StatefulElement.dependOnInheritedElement.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4761
#1      StatefulElement.dependOnInheritedElement 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4804
#2      Provider.of 
package:provider/src/provider.dart:213
#3      _DonorFormWrapperState.initState 
package:PlasmaBank/…/Home/donor_form_wrapper.dart:26
#4      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4640
...
```

[Here is the error I'm getting from my emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOvBi.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DonorFormHomeAfter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DonorFormHomeAfterState createState() => _DonorFormHomeAfterState();
}

class _DonorFormHomeAfterState extends State<DonorFormHomeAfter> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Data has been saved!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:PlasmaBank/screens/Donor/Home/donor_home_form.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DonorFormHomeBefore extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DonorFormHomeBeforeState createState() => _DonorFormHomeBeforeState();
}

class _DonorFormHomeBeforeState extends State<DonorFormHomeBefore> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Create New Donor'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DonorForm()),
                  );
          },
        ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class DonorWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<DonorUser>(context);
    print(user);

    // return either the Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null){
      return DonorAuthenticate();
    } else {
      return DonorHome();
    }
  }
}
```

Code works fine right now except, whenever I press the Form button from the nav bar, there comes an error for a blink of a second and the error goes away immediately. Here is the details:

```
class DonorFormWrapper extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  _DonorFormWrapperState createState() => _DonorFormWrapperState();
}

class _DonorFormWrapperState extends State<DonorFormWrapper>{

  bool before;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final DonorAuthService _auth = DonorAuthService();
    final user = Provider.of<DonorUser>(context);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _auth.getDatabaseInstance(user.uid),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot){
          if(snapshot.data['name']== 'name') {
            return DonorFormHomeBefore();
          }
          else if (snapshot.data['name'] != 'name') {
            return DonorFormHomeAfter();
          }
          else {
            return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(

              ),
            );
          }
      }
      );
  }
}
```

```
Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#f8ba4):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("name")

The relevant error-causing widget was
    FutureBuilder<dynamic> 
package:PlasmaBank/…/Home/donor_form_wrapper.dart:32
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _DonorFormWrapperState.build.<anonymous closure> 
package:PlasmaBank/…/Home/donor_form_wrapper.dart:35
#2      _FutureBuilderState.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:732
#3      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4619
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4502
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the snapshot has data before performing any action.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DonorFormWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DonorFormWrapperState createState() => _DonorFormWrapperState();
}

class _DonorFormWrapperState extends State<DonorFormWrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final DonorAuthService _auth = DonorAuthService();
    final user = Provider.of<DonorUser>(context);
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _auth.getDatabaseInstance(user.uid),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
            if (snapshot.data['name'] == 'name') {
              return DonorFormHomeBefore();
            }
            return DonorFormHomeAfter();
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! It worked! Really appreciate the help. Tons of thanks. You made my life great again :D

Answer (score 0):

When I test with making your code short, it works well. 
It seems that the problem is located other source.
 DonorFormHomeBefore() or DonorFormHomeAfter()[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "landRegistration App",
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
      home: DonorFormWrapper(),
    );
  }
}

class DonorFormWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DonorFormWrapperState createState() => _DonorFormWrapperState();
}

class _DonorFormWrapperState extends State<DonorFormWrapper> {
  Future<dynamic> _initUserFuture;
  bool before;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initUserFuture = getTest();
  }

  Future<dynamic> getTest() async {
    return await Future.value(42).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initUserFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          print(snapshot.data);
          if (snapshot.data == 42) {
            before = true;
            print(before);
            return Container(child: Text('1'));
          } else {
            before = false;
            print(before);
            return Container(child: Text('2'));
          }
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check the end of my thread, added the image of the emulator of what error I'm getting.

Comment: And, DonorFormHomeAfter and DonorFormHomeBefore are just two simple screen, still I added both of them at the end of my thread, please do check it.

Comment: could you add source related to 'PersistentTabView'?

Comment: Just added at the end of the thread. Please check now.

Comment: please check 'lib\…\Home\donor_home.dart:68'.
I can not found problem area with pices of code.

Comment: Thanks for the letting me know about FutureBuilder widget. Code works fine right now except, whenever I press the Form button from the nav bar, there comes an error for a blink of a second and the error goes away immediately. I've attached updated code and error in the end of my thread. Can you help me with it please?

Comment: I modified the code in my own way, it runs fine, except for a moment of error.

Comment: And, for some reason for that blink of a second, the CircularProgressIndicator is not working, if it was, I guess the problem wuld be solved.

Comment: There is a problem that excluded 'if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {'

`
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.data['name'] == 'name') {
              return DonorFormHomeBefore();
            } else if (snapshot.data['name'] != 'name') {
              return DonorFormHomeAfter();
            }
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
`